# How to upgrade ubuntu from 12.10 to 13.4 without lossing anything?

Tags: upgrade

well title says all most everything. I am using ubuntu 12.10. Installed using windows installer. Is there anyway to upgrade it? Any how much data i will lose? I have installed some softwares and there is some docs.

Comment: Take a look at [Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.04](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade).

Answer (score 0):

Just boot from any boot-able medium. You'll find an upgrade option, follow that. You'll loose nothing if you choose an upgrade.